# Remove rows if existing in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to search sheet_A for values in sheet_B / column A (starting from A2) and if they exist in sheet_A (column C, starting in C2) they get removed from sheet_A.

```
Sub Remover_Duplicados()

    'Backup to another sheet
    Const strSheetName As String = "BKP_sheet"
    Set wsTest = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsTest = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If wsTest Is Nothing Then
        Worksheets.Add.Name = strSheetName
    End If
    Sheets("sheet_A").Range("A1:BK3500").Copy Destination:=Sheets(strSheetName).Range("A1")

    'Search and destroy
    Dim searchableRange As Range
    Dim toRemoveRange As Range
    Dim lLoop As Long

    Set searchableRange = Worksheets("sheet_B").Range("A2", "A3500")
    Set toRemoveRange = Worksheets("sheet_A").Range("C2", "C3500")

    For lLoop = searchableRange.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(searchableRange, toRemoveRange(lLoop).Value) > 0 Then
            Worksheets("sheet_A").Rows(lLoop).Delete shift:=xlUp
        End If
    Next lLoop
End Sub
```

Sheet A, B and the result:
[image: result]

Some don't get removed.

Comment: Can you provide sample of your sheets?

Comment: @Zac - edited the issue

Comment: In the result, how come `4 / de/ 42` isn't included but `6 / _ / 4` is? Did you typo that, and the result should be the `4 / de/ 42`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gone through your code and amended it slightly to be more dynamic with the ranges, I've also used an Array to populate the values to be removed and then looped though that array to decide whether the row should be deleted or not:

```
Sub Remover_Duplicados()

    'Backup to another sheet
    Const strSheetName As String = "BKP_sheet"
    Dim wsA As Worksheet: Set wsA = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet_A")
    Dim wsB As Worksheet: Set wsB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet_B")
    Dim arrToRemove()

    Set wsTest = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
        Set wsTest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If wsTest Is Nothing Then
        Worksheets.Add.Name = strSheetName
    End If

    LastRowA = wsA.Cells(wsA.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    wsA.Range("A1:BK" & LastRowA).Copy Destination:=Sheets(strSheetName).Range("A1")

    LastRowB = wsB.Cells(wsB.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    arrToRemove = wsB.Range("A2:A" & LastRowB).Value

    For iRow = LastRowA To 2 Step -1
        For iArray = LBound(arrToRemove) To UBound(arrToRemove)
            If wsA.Cells(iRow, "C").Value = arrToRemove(iArray, 1) Then
                wsA.Rows(iRow).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
            End If
        Next iArray
    Next iRow
End Sub
```